# Cant import OnStateLoadedListeer

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Google Play Services. When I try to import the OnStateLoadedListener

```
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.OnStateLoadedListener;
```

AndroidStudio says "Cannot resolve Symbole OnStateLoadedListener"

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you extract the library? Did you add it to your project?

Comment: Do I need a special library for OnStateLoadedListener? Because I can Import com.google.android.gms.appstate. Only OnStateLoadedListener dont work.